# Java JOptionPane.showMessageDialog custom icon problem?

Tags: java, image, dialog, popup, message

So I have a pop-up dialog in my application that tells the user about the program. Everything was going fine until the custom icon. Here's what I've attempted:

**Attempt 1:**

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "Blah blah blah", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, new ImageIcon("home/user/Pictures/default.jpg"));
```

**Attempt 2:**

```
final icon = new ImageIcon("home/user/Pictures/default.jpg"));

    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(dialog, "Blah blah blah", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

**Attempt 3:**

```
final icon = new ImageIcon("home/user/Pictures/default.jpg"));
showMessageDialog(dialog, "Blah blah blah", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
```

**Attempt 4:**

(Screaming at java)

**Attempt 5:**

Using URL's

---

All have had no affect on the program and instead of an image, I don't get anything.

---

**Details:**

- No exceptions
- The file path DOES exist
- My IDE doesn't return exceptions, NOR any warnings of any sort
- Yes, I've put also tried the path /home/user/Pictures/default.jpg
- .ico's, .png's, .jpg's don't work. I'm not so sure about .gif's right now though.

Help me! :(

Comment: have you tried to put `/home/user...` instead of `home/user...` because otherwise it looks for a home directory from the place you execute the app, which only works if you execute it in `/`.

Comment: Yeah, you're not looking in the right place. Do you know for a fact where your user directory is? `System.out.println(System.getProperty("user.dir"));`

Comment: Also, is this in a jar file or an applet?

Comment: This is a .class file compiled by Eclipse. The command you gave me returns null.

Comment: It's not supposed to return anything. Does it print anything out on the console though?

Comment: Yeah. It prints "null" in the console.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\John\\Desktop\\lol.jpg");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Blah blah blah", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
    }
}
```

Here is a variant that uses a URL:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.net.*;

public class TestIcon
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(new URL("http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a1ab0af4997654345d7a949877f8037e?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG"));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Blah blah blah", "About", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, icon);
    }
}
```

Comment: The second source (using an URL) works for me.  I am pretty sure the paths are failing because the current directory is not where the OP thinks it is.

Comment: @Andrew: Several here including me have been trying to say that to him for a while, but he won't believe us. That's why I'm trying to get him to see where his user directory is, but he seems to be ignoring that comment of mine. This is getting frustrating.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is a little old, but as there was no reply that solved my question, after some research this is what worked for me (working with java 1.7):

I have used the `getClass().getResource(<path>)`  method like this:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource(<pathToIcon>));
```

It seems to me as a good practice to create a 'resources' folder in your project, and inside it a 'icons' folder, and to refer to that location every-time you need an icon (or anything else such as audio files, images etc)

Answer (score 0):

Here this may help: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html

Comment: It's not that I can't do that; I'm trying to use the built in function of JOptionPane to display an icon.

Comment: @Ken `JOptionPane.showMessageDialog("whatever.gif","whatever")`. This is assuming the icon is in the working directory of the java process.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
BufferedImage myPicture = null;
try
{
    myPicture = ImageIO.read(new File("home/user/Pictures/default.jpg"));
}
catch(Exception ex){}
panel.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon(myPicture)));
panel.add(new JLabel("blah blah blah"));
Object[] options = {};
JOptionPane pane = new JOptionPane();
pane.showOptionDialog(null, panel, "About", JOptionPane.NO_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, null, options, null);
```

Answer (score 0):

The same thing happened to me, thank God I looked that my image was loaded not in the 'source' file, it was in 'bin' file.. the path was wrong

```
ImageIcon preg1 = new ImageIcon("C:\\Java\\TestPsicologico\\bin\\Preg1.jpg");
```

Answer (score 0):

Everyone was right it's just that the path copied is incorrect.

You just have to place the preferred image in your ***project's folder*** 
and your image will show up in the project navigation tab , after that just copy the image path and paste it into:

```
final ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("*Paste copied path*");


 JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, infoMessage, " " + titleBar, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE,icon);
```